# Windows application(Vb .net) with Service-based Database I want share this database to many users (in Local Area Network)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows

I create windows application in Vb .net. I create service based database (mdf file). And I used connection strings to connect in my database.
But I want this database in one Computer and others computers connect (in small networks that) in database how can I do that with programs with free license ?

Which is the easy way ?

Comment: Sorry slightly confused with your question. :( if you are using connection string than you can define service account in connection string and connect to database from any computer on the network on the network?

Comment: Now i have one mdf file in my computer in C:\Database\data.mdf if i make my program exe i use |Datadirectory| in my connection string like : "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True".
And if install the program in computer, the computer have the own  database.mdf. I want have one database.mdf and other computer connect there.

Comment: What about something like this?                                          "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Uid=ServiceUserName;pwd=ServiceAccountPassword"

Comment: Yes but i want a server to but my mdf file.
Can you tell me the best way to do that?

Thank you